# A Simple AJAX with JSP example

Tags: java, ajax, jsp, asynchronous

I am trying to learn AJAX with JSP and I have written the following code. This does not seem to be working. Kindly help:

This is my configuration_page.jsp

```
    <html>
     <head>
     <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
     <title>JSP Page</title>
     <script type="text/javascript">

      function loadXMLDoc()
      {
        var xmlhttp;
        var config=document.getElementById('configselect').value;
        var url="get_configuration.jsp";
        if (window.XMLHttpRequest)
        {
            xmlhttp=new XMLHttpRequest();
        }
        else
        {
            xmlhttp=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
        }
        xmlhttp.onreadystatechange=function()
        {
            if (xmlhttp.readyState==4 && xmlhttp.status==200)
            {
                document.getElementById("myDiv").innerHTML=xmlhttp.responseText;
            }
        }

        xmlhttp.open("GET", url, true);
        xmlhttp.send();
}
</script>        

</head>

<body>
  <h2 align="center">Saved Configurations</h2>
   Choose a configuration to run: 
  <select name="configselect" width="10">
    <option selected value="select">select</option>
    <option value="Config1">config1</option>
    <option value="Config2">config2</option>
    <option value="Config3">config3</option>
  </select> 
  <button type="button" onclick='loadXMLDoc()'> Submit </button>
  <div id="myDiv">
    <h4>Get data here</h4>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

This is my get_configuration.jsp which I am trying to access from the AJAX code above:

```
<html>
  <head>
      <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
      <title>JSP Page</title>

  </head>
  <body>

    <h4>Mee..</h4> 
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: If the result of get_configuration.jsp is used as the content of a div, then it should not contain `<html>`, `<head>`, `<body>`. It should just contain the `<h4>`. Do yourself a favor, and use jQuery.

Comment: Also suggest to use jQuery: it has simpler syntax and crossbrowser portability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are doing mistake in "configuration_page.jsp" file.
here in this file , function loadXMLDoc() 's line number 2 should be like this:

```
var config=document.getElementsByName('configselect').value;
```

because you have declared only the `name` attribute in your `<select>` tag. So you should get this element by name.

After correcting this, it will run without any JavaScript error

Answer (score 16):

I have used [jQuery AJAX](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) to make AJAX requests.

Check the following code:

```
<html>
<head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function() {
            $('#call').click(function ()
            {
                $.ajax({
                    type: "post",
                    url: "testme", //this is my servlet
                    data: "input=" +$('#ip').val()+"&output="+$('#op').val(),
                    success: function(msg){      
                            $('#output').append(msg);
                    }
                });
            });

        });
    </script>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>JSP Page</title>
</head>
<body>
    input:<input id="ip" type="text" name="" value="" /><br></br>
    output:<input id="op" type="text" name="" value="" /><br></br>
    <input type="button" value="Call Servlet" name="Call Servlet" id="call"/>
    <div id="output"></div>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0):

loadXMLDoc JS function should return false, otherwise it will result in postback.