# How to add Message box instead of new window in jsp

Tags: java, javascript, jsp

What I have tried is

```
First.jsp
   <form name = "button" style="VISIBILITY: visible">
                    <table cellspacing=5 cellpadding=5 bgcolor="lightblue" colspan=2 rowspan=2 align="center">
     <TR> <TD> <INPUT TYPE="button" onclick="sub1();hide();" VALUE="DOWNLOAD"></TD>
    <script>
     function popup()
                    {
                        popupWindow = window.open('delete','name','width=300,height=100');
                        popupWindow.focus();
                        window.close();     
                    }
```

delete.jsp

```
<%
String Pdfpath=   session.getAttribute("pdfpath").toString();
 File f =new File(Pdfpath);

 Boolean flag=false;
  if(f.exists())
  {
    flag=f.delete();
  }
  else 
  {
    out.println("File not found to delete");
  }

%>
<html>
<head>
<title>Delete file in java</title>
</head>

<body>
<%
 if(flag==true)
 {
  out.println("File Has Bean deleted successfully");
 }
 else
 {
  out.println("Error: Unable To Delete The File");
 }
%>
</body>
</html>
```

From my first jsp I'm passing some path to another delete.jsp  on the button click.That jsp delete the file on my directory and giving an message.I want that message to comes of in a message box at the same time that window should not come.

I don't like add all deletion code in javascript function so that I'm going for another jsp. Is it possible to hide the window and show only the confirm message box in delete.jsp page.I need some help.

Thanks

Comment: Use JSTL and EL as much as you can :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use the following code as delete.jsp ;)

```
<%
    String Pdfpath = session.getAttribute("pdfpath").toString();
    File f = new File(Pdfpath);

    Boolean flag = false;
    if (f.exists()) {
        flag = f.delete();
    } else {
        out.println("File not found to delete");
    }
%>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Delete file in java</title>
    </head>

    <body>
        <%
            String message = "";
            if (flag == true) {
                message = "File Has Bean deleted successfully";
            } else {
                message = "Error: Unable To Delete The File";
            }
        %>
        <script type="text/javascript">
            alert('<%=message%>');
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: The new window is still there.Is there a way to hide that window??

Comment: what do you mean of new window? Do you mean delete.jsp?

Comment: OK ... You can use an ajax call to a servlet or a jsp to do the delete process (instead of post the first page to delete.jsp) then get response and show the message box, So you can eliminate the second window ;) ... These links may be useful: 1)[AJAX with JSP and Servlet using Jquery Example](http://www.programming-free.com/2012/08/ajax-with-jsp-and-servlet-using-jquery.html) and 2) [A Simple AJAX with JSP example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907383/a-simple-ajax-with-jsp-example)