# Pass Javascript Value to Java in JSP

Tags: java, javascript, ajax, jsp, parameters

I would like to pass a Javascript value to a Java function in JSP. How can I do that?
The id comes from a combobox in JSP via Javascript. I will get the ID from ComboBox and send it to Java function as parameter to get the Java result.

```
function Display()
{
   var IdFromCB = (document.getElementById("MListSelect")).value;
   //CALL JAVA FUNCTION HERE BY USING IdFromCB as function parameter
   //'<% getSomething(-----IdFromCB-----);%>'

}
```

Thanks,Mark

Comment: Karan, Please go through the lifecycle of JSP to better understand why it is not possible.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You cannot make a server call directly. You need to make a server request.

**javascript** plays on client side and **JSP** plays on server side.

What you need is you have to make a server request. And send that string as a query parameter.

Two options to achieve this.

- [`HTML forms`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html401/interact/forms.html)
- [`Ajax`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ajax_%28programming%29).

Do not confuse that JSP and java script existed on same document(or file). Yes but JSP part compiles on server side  and JavaScript executes by browser.

Answer (score 1):

Javascript statements are rendered by Browsers and executed as client program.

In your case if you want execute a java code based on selection of html component, you would need to use `ajax` call .

You can find quick example here

[A Simple AJAX with JSP example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907383/a-simple-ajax-with-jsp-example)

http://www.programming-free.com/2013/03/ajax-fetch-data-from-database-in-jsp.html