# Javascript passing value to label field in JSP

Tags: javascript, jsp

Can anyone help me on how to pass value from a Javascript to a label field in JSP?

Comment: could you explain a little more what you want to do, the context and what you tried to resolve your problem?

Comment: Java server pages executed at your servers, javascript, on the contrary, executes at clients' browsers. Please take this into account.

Comment: Are js and jsp on the same page? Does page gets submitted to show the text?

Answer (score 0):

Javascript runs on the client whereas JSP runs on the server. this two cannot
communicate each other directly. You can take help of AJAX to solve your problem. Otherwise, you can submit your form. Like below

```
<input type="hidden" name="variableName" value="">
In Javascript you can do:
document.form.variableName.value="value";
form.submit();
```

Comment: can i able to pass without using document.form.variableName.value?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you can't do it. You must understand first how a JSP page works. A JSP is a 'Servlet' that executes in the server side. The servlet is executed in your JBoss, Tomcat or whatever application server, then an HTML+Javascript is generated and sent to the browser, so the JSP variables don't exist anymore, so it's impossible to pass a value from Javascript to something that doesn't exist.

On the other hand, if you mean you want to pass a value from Javascript to a HTML field that has been generated via JSP, then yes you can do it. For example:

Field

```
<input id="myField" type="text" value=""/>
```

Javascript

```
var myValue = 'Hello';
document.getElementById("myField").value = 'Hello';
```

Answer (score 0):

Javascript and jsps are two different languages. It doesn't matter if JS and JSP are in same page (same file). JS is compiled by the Web browser(@ client side) and JSP is compiled by the Server (obviously @ server side).

Refer this link
[Pass Javascript Value to Java in JSP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20677707/pass-javascript-value-to-java-in-jsp)