# How to include new page on jsp page in every 10 sec?

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, jsp

Hi i am trying to include a new jsp page on my jsp page in every 10 sec how can i achieve this

i am able to include page but not including  according to time

Here is my  code

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html;charset=UTF-8" %>
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" 
<html>
<head>
<title>Untitled Document</title>
  section
 {height:70%; background-color:blue; display:block; overflow:auto;}

section .push {height:500px;}
</style>
</head>
 <body>
    <form action="F1.jsp" method="post"> 
     <%@ include file="F2.jsp" %> 
      <footer>footer</footer>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

How can i achieve this

Thanks in advance

Comment: try a javascript timer

Comment: If by that you mean to include f3.jsp, f4.jsp and so on every 10sec, it would be hard/messy to do it via JSP. You probably need to learn AJAX and partial html update.

Comment: Can we know your business need for this?

Comment: @Vignesh Vino i need to show different different information on different pages

Comment: Using JSP includes for this is a bad idea. Use Ajax calls.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to include more content or refresh a section of the page you need to use browser side JavaScript to pull new content from the server.

Answer (score 1):

Once you display something using JSP, that is final. It cannot change unless you provide the mechanisms to change. You can set a refresh rate of your JSP to auto refresh and display each time a new content.

Or you can use AJAX.

How to do it using [ajax](http://api.jquery.com/category/ajax/) (I prefer the JQuery version) can be found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907383/a-simple-ajax-with-jsp-example) at the answer with 5 upvotes

Answer (score 0):

You can [set interval](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setInterval) in Javascript.

**`syntax:`**

```
setInterval(function(){
    // code //
},10000);
```

In the code you can use `Ajax calls` which pool the content of JSP from the server.