# Redirecting to a jsp page from a webservice

Tags: java, web-services, jsp

I am having a Webservice running in Tomcat server. It gets input from the user and appends hello to it. Now, I want this **Hello + entered input** to be displayed in a jsp page. Is it possible to send the value from the java program to the jsp page directly. If so please tell me how this can be done ?

Any help or sample program would be highly appreciated.

Attaching my java code here

> 

```
import javax.jws.WebService;
import javax.jws.WebMethod;

@WebService
public class Hello {
    private String message = new String("Hello, ");
    String name1;

    public Hello() {
    }

    @WebMethod
    public String sayHello(String name) throws Exception {
        this.name1 = name;
        System.out.println("The value of name1 is " + name1);
        return message + name + ".";
    }
}
```

Thanks,

Comment: How it got input from the user? Are you making Ajax call to web service?

Comment: No. I have the client running. It has a basic input field right. I am entering the value there. I want this value to be directly displayed in a JSP page.

Comment: if you want, the value entered in the text box to be send to web service and response from the service to be displayed in the page..check out http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907383/a-simple-ajax-with-jsp-example

Comment: But is not possible to directly send data from webservice to JSP page ? My requirement is like i need to send the data which the user enters while invoking the webservice to a jsp page for displaying purpose. ? Kindly help !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It's not possible and here's why:

The web service call is an XML-formatted SOAP message sent to your web service. The client calling your web service is doing so, with the expectation that a similarly-formatted web service response is going to be sent back. What you are asking here is that rather than sending the expected XML-formatted SOAP response that you've promised your web service client (by way of publishing a WSDL), you're going to send back an HTML document instead. See the problem?

**Bottom line : You cannot respond to a SOAP request with an HTML (or JSP-generated HTML) response**

Answer (score -1):

Getting the user input from the first page:

```
String userInput = request.getParameter("userInput");
```

In the java code to forward data to the asp file

```
String url = "/WEB-INF/JSP/display.jsp"; //Assumes this exists
RequestDispatcher rd = getServletContext().getRequestDispatcher(url);
request.setAttribute("userInput", userInput);
rd.forward(request,response);
```

In the JSP

```
<%
      String userInput = (String) request.getAttribute("userInput");
%>
```

To print it in the JSP

```
<h1><%=userInput%></h1>
```

EDIT:
My apologies, my first answer was pertaining to Apache Tomcat not jws.

See this section of this guide: [Developing a Web client for Calculator](http://geronimo.apache.org/GMOxDOC30/developing-a-simple-calculator-web-service.html#DevelopingasimpleCalculatorWebservice-DevelopingaWebclientforCalculator)

It appears as though you simply forward the form action on the initial HTML page to a separate results page which will make use of the web service you have created.

Comment: No problem, here are a few examples with JSP: https://www3.ntu.edu.sg/home/ehchua/programming/java/JSPByExample.html If you get it working with this, mark the answer as correct for future viewers.

Comment: Hi Gleason, Thanks for your help. I have attached my code for your check as well. My need is to directly send the data from this java code to web page. Is this possible. Because it is not possible to include servlet functions here right ?

Comment: @Kirthika, no its not possible. The web service returns to the caller. The servlet (or a jsp) responds to a http request from a browser. These are 2 different actions not related to each other. What are you trying to achieve ?

Comment: @ramp, My scenario is user invokes my webservice from another end.. say for ex: SOAPUI. The response i need to display in a web page directly without any halt in between. Once the user invokes the webservice, I need to display the response in the UI. So I wanted to redirect to jsp page from my webservice code which I am unable to do. Kindly help whether this is possible or not.

Thanks

Comment: No. As I said these are 2 different actions. The SOAPUI response returns to the SOAPUI. The UI (assuming its a browser since you have mentioned a jsp) receives a response when it makes a request. You cannot pipe the response of the web service to a browser. It is not natural.

Comment: You could do  things in an indirect way. 1. Store the web service response somewhere (say, in a servletcontext) 2. have the browser keep pinging the server with ajax requests and send the web service response back as the ajax response.

Comment: @ramp, Thanks for the reply. I will try it out in the way you mentioned :)