# Passing Data from JSP to Servlets from HTML page dynamically

Tags: java, jsp, servlets, primefaces, dynamic-binding

I have a JSP page which reads data from HTML and has CSS,Jquery code in it .
Now my webpage in jsp has two text labels and a add button next to them. 
User can enter any no of values in the text field.

Now my requirement is that every time user enters the alue in these fields and clicks on add then that data should be passed on to my servlet. Servlet will basically do some validation and return a boolean variable. 
Based on the value of this boolean, I shall change the appearance of my text boxes.

This is required to be done for every time user clicks on Add button. 
How can I achieve this ?

My HTML code :

```
<div id="id1" name="id1" style="display: none;">Add a node: </br>
<input type="text" name="ipaddress" id="ipaddress" placeholder="Enter Node IP"> <input type="text" name="port" id="port" placeholder="Enter Node Port">
<input type="button" value="Add" name="addnodebutton" id="addnodebutton"/>
</div>
```

The value in ipaddress and port shall be passed on to my servlet and depending on return parameter, their appearance should change.

Can anyone enlighten me how this is actually going to work ? 
TIA :)

Comment: Where are the servlets?

Comment: Were you able to solve this?

Comment: Yes, but I had used web services.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For passing data to and from a servlet, you have options.

Option 1- You can wrap your html in a form tag and set the action/method properties for your servlet/http method like below:

```
<form method="POST" action="servletname">
<input type="text" name="ipaddress" id="ipaddress" placeholder="Enter Node IP">   
<input type="text" name="port" id="port" placeholder="Enter Node Port">
<input type="submit" value="Add" name="addnodebutton" id="addnodebutton"/>
</form>
```

The submit would send a request with the input to your servlet. You would then need to handle your request parameters in your servlet, set your values/flags in your response object and forward to the user or jsp/html page of your choice.

Option 2- You can make an ajax call from your jsp, process your input and return a response to your page asynchronously. Example below:
[A Simple AJAX with JSP example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907383/a-simple-ajax-with-jsp-example)