# Auto-update JSP page on timer

Tags: javascript, java, spring-boot, jsp

I have a monitoring dashboard which runs java spring as the backend and has a jsp front end. Currently I add everything to a ModelAndView including the object which stores all the data and display that in jsp. Setting the @Scheduled does run the method as expected every minute but doesn't output the updated info to the browser.

Is there a way to automatically get this data without having to refresh the page each time? Code examples of what I'm doing below.

Java controller

```
@Scheduled(fixedRate = 60000)
@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET) // Set this to run every minute and return via @SendTo using the websockets
public ModelAndView getHome() {
    Wrapper wrapper = new Wrapper();
    UATIssues uatIssues = backgroundJobService.runGetCurrentUATIssues();
    wrapper.setUatIssues(uatIssues);
    ModelAndView modelAndView = new ModelAndView();
    modelAndView.addObject("wrapper", wrapper);
    modelAndView.setViewName("home");
    return modelAndView;
}
```

Jsp file

```
<table class="uatIssue">
<c:if test="${not empty uatTicketNumList}">
  <c:forEach items="${uatTicketNumList}" var="uatTicketNumList">
    <tr><td>${uatTicketNumList}</td></tr>
  </c:forEach>
</c:if>
```

Answer (score 1):

Which browser/client would you like your `@Scheduled` method to return to?

This will NOT work this way. 
`@Scheduled` annotation is used to do some operations/jobs on the **server side**. It has no idea about the requester (your browser - client side).

In order to have the `fresh` data, you need to either:

1) Call your `Controller`'s endpoint from your JSP page on a time basis, i.e. every 2 minutes and then parse the data (`AJAX`). Example: [A Simple AJAX with JSP example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8907383/a-simple-ajax-with-jsp-example)

or

2) Implement web sockets and when the changes occur your frontend will be informed immediately. More: https://spring.io/guides/gs/messaging-stomp-websocket/

Comment: I might try implementing the web sockets. Will this still support returning Java objects and accessing them in the same way I currently am?

Comment: You can return any Java object using the websockets

Comment: By the way, it's the more difficult solution. But following this tutorial you'll get ther I'm sure.